# Node created at runtime will not start

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having some trouble getting a node that is created at run time to be "recognized".  Here is the node class:

```
class node {
    private:
        ros::NodeHandle *n;

    public:
        node() { n = NULL; }
        ros::NodeHandle getHandle() { return *n; }
        init(int argc, char **argv, std::string s) {
            ros::init(argc, argv, s);
        }
        void create() {
            if (n == NULL) { n = new ros::NodeHandle(); }
        }
};
```

I use the node class inside of a coorinator

```
class coordinator {
    private:
        node myNode;
        /** Pub, Subs, etc go here */
    public:
        void setup(int argc, char **argv, std::string s) {
            myNode.init(argc, argv, s);
            myNode.create();
            /* setup pubs, subs etc using myNode.getHandle() */
        }
};
int main(int argc, char **arv) {
    ros::init(argc, argc, "starter");
    coordinator c;
    c.init(argc, argv, "coordinator");
    c.setup();
    ...
}
```

When I call `c.setup()` from a main method of another node, the newly created node doesn't show up using `rosnode list` and clients that requests its services wait forever.  I can't use `rosspawn` because I'm using ros fuerte.

EDIT: I even tried to pass the main methods node handle into the node constructor but it still doesn't get recognized.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64530/node-created-at-runtime-will-not-start/) by [kaoao](https://answers.ros.org/users/5069/kaoao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2013-06-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know, roscpp only creates one node per process.  Multiple calls to `ros::init()` will not actually create multiple nodes.  This function actually protects itself against repeated calls using an `initialized` flag to bypass many operations if called more than once.

If you need to create multiple nodes in a single process, I suggest you look into [nodelets](http://ros.org/wiki/nodelet).  These are fully supported, and are the typical method used to combine nodes for image processing.

See [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/11018/how-to-spawn-multiple-nodes-in-same-c-process/) for more discussion.

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1